# Mono, mysql, fluent nhibernate and a TdsInternalException

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, mono, fluent

Trying to connect to MySQL, using fluent nhibernate and Mono... and getting this error:

```
TdsInternalException: Server does not exist or connection refused.
```

I know my mysql credentials work because non-nhibernate connections are successful at creating tables, reading data, etc.  It only crashes when I try to connect with fluent nhibernate

This is the mysql connection string:

```
Server=localhost,3306;Database=mydb;uid=theUser;pwd=thePassword
```

Here is the Fluent Nhibernate configuration code:

```
var configuration = Fluently.Configure();
configuration.Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard
            .ConnectionString(sqlConnectionStr));

// mappings
sessionFactory = configuration.Mappings... so on....
```

This is the full error:

```
 [exec] !! An error has occurred.  The error is:
 [exec] FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
 [exec]
 [exec]  ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Server does not exist or connection refused. ---> Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsInternalException: Server does not exist or connection refused. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
 [exec]   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 [exec]   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70..ctor (System.String server, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion version) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds80..ctor (System.String server, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionPoolManager.CreateConnection (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionInfo info) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionPool.GetConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 [exec]   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 [exec]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: It seems weird that SqlConnection is getting used here - are you sure you aren't using an MS SQL configuration somewhere?

Comment: I'm getting the same exception when working with TcpClient. It throws this at 'await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ip, port)' but works fine if I introduce a 1s delay before this statement!

Answer (score 2):

Should it be:

```
Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=mydb;Uid=theUser;Pwd=thePassword;
```

Instead of (`;` instead of `,`)

```
Server=localhost,3306;Database=mydb;uid=theUser;pwd=thePassword
```